# Address difference between two integer variables in c

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main()
{
    int i=10,j=20,diff;
    diff=&j-&i;
    printf("\nAddress of i=%u Address of j=%u",&i,&j);
    printf("\nDifference of address i and j is %d\n",diff);
    return 0;
}
```

The output I got is:

```
Address of i=3012788 Address of j=3012776
Difference of address i and j is -3
```

But the difference between the addresses here is 2.

When I do `diff=&i-&j`, I get the following output:

```
Address of i=2751740 Address of j=2751728
Difference of address i and j is 3
```

But the difference here between the addresses is 12.

When two integer variables are declared, its not necessary for the second variable to occupy the next four bytes of the address occupied by the first variable. But why the differences are not actually what it has to be?

Comment: Ignoring the fact that your ptr difference is undefined, in general if you want to do ptr difference you should use [ptrdiff_t](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstddef/ptrdiff_t/)

Comment: At this point, if you truly want to know what happened (why the compiler changed the ordering of the ints and inserted some space) you should write what OS you are using (and if 32 or 64 bits), what compiler you used (and which version) and what parameters you passed to it. Then perhaps someone will be able to tell you why THAT compiler on THAT platform does THAT things.

Comment: i'm using windows 7 - 32 bit OS and visual studio2008 for compiling the c programs.

Comment: Found. The Visual C++ in Debug mode adds some stack guards around your variables, so that you don't corrupt them with "wrong" pointer arithmetic. He then reorders the variables, so in memory they are: diff, (8 byte space), j, (8 byte space), i. Try adding this code before the end of the program: *(&j + 1) = 0; and launch it: the debugger will signal a stack corruption around the variable j.

Comment: @xanatos:I did as you tod me to do and it thrown an error message that the stack around the variable j is corrupted.&j+1 = address of j+size of int. so it will move to the next 4 bytes. whichh corrupts the address of i too.Please correct me if my assumption about this is wrong.

Comment: *(&j + 2) = 0 will corrupt another piece of stack. I don't know if VC++ will "attribute" that space to j or to i, but technically it isn't neither. It's simply "stack that shouldn't be addressed".

Comment: @xanatos:thanks xantos for explaining me clearly and patiently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, **it's not legal to do arithmetic on addresses that are not from the same block of memory** (array etc).

You second question is more interesting. You are subtracting two addresses and it defies arithmetic. Here is what is happening.

This is how pointer arithmetic works:

- `pointer + x` actually means `pointer + sizeof *pointer`
- `pointer1 - pointer2` actually means `(pointer1 - pointer2) / sizeof *either`

So you expect `12` and you get `3 = 12 / 4`. That's because an `int` on your platform is 4 bytes long.

Comment: :Thanks for explaining clearly.Address of i=3012788 Address of j=3012776 Difference of address i and j is -3.but the difference is 2 so 2/4 is 0.5 . how this will be represented.Please help me understand this.

Comment: @angus No, the difference is in "steps" of sizeof(int). So your diff of 3 is 12 bytes (sizeof(int) = 4 on your platform). And you don't know how the compiler "positioned" the ints on the stack.

Comment: I have used these conversions before in my programs without knowing it.I could understand now how the 3 diff is.Thanks. but how is the  -3 difference came from the subtraction i=3012788 and j=3012776.I could not understand that.

Comment: @Angus You wrote `int i, j, diff`, the compiler translated in `int j, _hidden1, _hidden2, i, diff`. He is free to do it. Now... Don't ask me why it did it.

Answer (score 3):

Computing the difference between pointers that do not point into the same array (as in your case) is undefined behavior in C. See [this](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/ARR36-C.+Do+not+subtract+or+compare+two+pointers+that+do+not+refer+to+the+same+array) for more information and references.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try:

```
    diff=(int)&j-(int)&i;
```

Answer (score 2):

When an 2 integer variables are declared its not necessary for the second variable to occupy the next four bytes of the address occupied by the first variable?

NO, The address can be anywhere, the compiler chosses, unless ofcourse you have an array.

Answer (score 1):

You are using pointer arithmetic. Because int is 4 bytes on your machine, result * 4 is the distance between the two address. However you can apply conversion like (int) on the pointers to get what you expected.